# Pascal Triangle Reaching limit

Tags: java, algorithm

So what is happening is when the triangle gets to row 13-14 the numbers either become too big or do not calculate correctly. Either way I have been stuck on this for a while. I see no reason for calculations to work perfectly up until these higher numbers. Could it be that the values are exceeding the limit for an integer or what can be contained within a method?
Any input or help would be much appreciated.

```
public class Pascal { 

/** 
* @param args 
*/ 
public static void main(String[] args) { 

 for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){ 
 for(int j = 0; j <= i; j++){ 
       System.out.print(Pascal.factorial(i) / (Pascal.factorial(j) * Pascal.factorial(i
 - j)) + " "); 
 } 
 System.out.println(); 
} 
} 

public static int factorial(int num){ 
 int num2 = 1; 
 for(int i = num; i >= 2; i--){ 
      num2 *= i; 
 } 
 return num2; 
} 

 }
```

Comment: yes, this is because limits of integer, use BigInteger for factorials

Comment: at row 13 though? The numbers there are hardly in the thousands

Comment: I take that back, I see Tanner is computing them from the factorials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, 12! = 479,001,600 fits into a 32-bit integer but 13! = 6,227,020,800 does not.

Still, there is [another formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient#Recursive_formula) for binomial coefficients involving only addition. If you use that one, you won't have to use a larger type as long as the end result fits into your type.

Comment: A simpler way to see the formula (for those not versed in combinatorics) is to look at a picture of Pascal's triangle: every number with the exception of the outer 1's is the sum of the two numbers directly above.

Comment: Could I stick with my method and use "BigInteger" somehow?

Comment: yeah just look up how to use BigIntegers and modify your factorial accordingly

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the `factorial` method of evaluating the Pascal's triangle. Any algorithm involving factorials **will fail eventually**, unless you restrict your calculations with some bounds (no matter what datatype you use, unless it's some special arbitrary sized data-type/structure)

You'll need to use more efficient algorithms to generate the binomial coefficients so that you don't burst through the limits.

Here is a sample algo in pseudocode ([source](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient))

```
Function nCk (n, k)
Begin:

if k < 0 Or k > n
    return 0
else if k = 0 Or k = n
    return 1

k = min(k, n-k) // Fewer interations as nCk = nC(n-k)

Temp = 1
for i = 0 to k - 1
    Temp = Temp * (n - 1) / (i + 1)
loop
return Temp
```

Also, if you would like to calculate even larger values very efficiently without iterating, you can use **Ramanujan's formula** for approximating factorials (then you can write nCr in terms of logarithms and the divisions of huge numbers will become additions and subtractions of manageable numbers)

Here is a great source to learn more about the efficient computation of factorials and related functions (http://www.johndcook.com/blog/2012/09/25/ramanujans-factorial-approximation/)